# flask development single terminal: continue editing Code without quitting flask

Tags: flask, terminal

Background: I am new to Flask (and fairly new to python, linux terminal, servers).  I have gone through the tutorial http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/.
I am developing on raspberry pi 3, via putty from my PC.
I run flask, according to the tutorial:
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
According to the tutorial I can make changes to the code and the server will automatically reload.

My issue: I don't know how to make changes to my code without stopping Flask (ctrl+c).
How can I leave Flask, return to the Linux Terminal, edit my code, and then return to the Flask Debugger without stopping Flask each time?
I have reviewed the Flask Docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/ to no avail.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You has to enable the debug mode. Default debug is True in flask

```
app.run(debug=True) or export DEBUG=True
```

you can go through this link for Flask configuration 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables

If you are using Flask >=1.0v you need to set environment in development mode.

```
 export FLASK_ENV='development'
```